# Grouping similar plots together in a stripchart

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have groups of data that I want to put more closely together on my strip charts

```
stripchart(refined$lowfeq ~ refined$taxa, 
           vertical=T, las=2, pch=c(20,20,1,1,0,0,0,11,11,6,17), col=boxcol, 
           xaxt="n", ylab="Frequency (kHz)")
axis(1, las=2, cex.axis = 0.9, font.axis = 3, at=c(1:11), labels=1:11)`
```

[image]

I want to put the following groups together:
1 and 2, 3 and 4, 5-7, 8 and 9. With 10 and 11 individually spaced.

I tried to get that with this but it did not work out. The spaces existed but the last 3 plots are missing.

```
stripchart(refined$lowfeq ~ refined$taxa, 
           vertical=T, las=2, pch=c(20,20,1,1,0,0,0,11,11,6,17), col=boxcol, 
           xaxt="n",  ylab="Frequency (kHz)",at=c(1,2,4,5,7,8,9,11,12,14,15))
axis(1, las=2, cex.axis = 0.9, font.axis = 3, at=c(1,2,4,5,7,8,9,11,12,14,15), labels=1:11)`
```

[image]

How do I get the spaces without losing the last 3 plots?

I am aiming for something that looks like the box plots here, but couldn't get it even though I followed it:

http://www.r-bloggers.com/box-plot-with-r-tutorial/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying `xlim` should get what you want:

```
library(RColorBrewer)

refined <- data.frame(lowfeq=runif(300, 0.3, 0.7),
                      taxa=sample(1:11, 300, replace=TRUE))

boxcol <- brewer.pal(11, "Set3")

stripchart(refined$lowfeq ~ refined$taxa, xlim=c(1,15),
           vertical=T, las=2, pch=c(20,20,1,1,0,0,0,11,11,6,17), col=boxcol, 
           xaxt="n",  ylab="Frequency (kHz)", at=c(1,2,4,5,7,8,9,11,12,14,15))
axis(1, las=2, cex.axis = 0.9, font.axis = 3, at=c(1,2,4,5,7,8,9,11,12,14,15), labels=1:11)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One can use table like following with ggplot code to add spaces in axis:

```
> refined
   taxa lowfreq group
1     1       2     a
2     1       3     a
3     1       6     a
4     1       5     a
5     1       8     a
6     1       9     a
7     2       2     a
8     2       3     a
9     2       5     a
10    2       6     a
11    2       4     a
12    2       5     a
13    2       1     a
14    3       2     b
15    3       6     b
16    3       5     b
17    3       8     b
18    3       4     b
19    3       5     b
20    _       0  <NA>

ggplot(refined)+geom_point(aes(x=taxa, y=lowfreq))+scale_x_discrete(breaks=c('1','2','_','3'))
```

[image]

Or one can simply give different colors to different groups (I think this is a much better approach):

```
ggplot(refined[1:19,])+geom_point(aes(x=taxa, y=lowfreq, color=group), size=5)
```

[image]